# How to show $E(\hat{y}|y)=E(E(\hat{y}|\theta,y)|y)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

I am reading the following section of "bayesian data analysis" by Gelman. I do not quite understand why $E(\hat{y}|y)=E(E(\hat{y}|\theta,y)|y)$.
[image]

It would be nice if you can also explain the equation for the variance.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the tower law for conditional expectation. If you understand why $E(E(Y\mid X)) = E(Y),$ think about doing this same computation, only instead of averaging over the whole probability space, doing it conditionally on a third random variable $Z.$ You'd get $$ E(E(Y\mid X,Z)\mid Z) = E(Y\mid Z).$$

Similarly, the variance equation is just the familiar law of total variance $$ Var(X) = E(Var(X\mid Y)) + Var(E(X\mid Y))$$ which will also go through when you condition on some random variable $Z$ at the outset. So it becomes $$ Var(X\mid Z) = E(Var(X\mid Y)\mid Z)+Var(E(X\mid Y)\mid Z)$$

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Can you clarify a bit "doing it conditionally on a third random variable Z", why you can just add a condition term?

Comment: @Roger Think of it like a Venn diagram: conditioning on the event $Z=z $ just restricts the sample space to the event $Z=z$. Probability goes on as usual within this subset... you might even forget about the universe outside that space if you aren't interested in it. From another angle, who's to say the original sample space $\Omega$ you were considering isn't an event of some larger space $\Omega'$ with $P(\Omega)=1$ so that we're always secretly conditioning on $\Omega$. (Maybe we even have $P(\Omega)\ne 1$... someone flipped a coin and made us consider $\Omega$ rather than another space).

Comment: @Roger Also if you're familar with $\sigma$ algebras, the algebra generated by $Y$ and $Z$ is finer than the one generated by $Z,$ so the expectation result follows from the tower law for conditional expectations wrt $\sigma$ algebras where when you re-condition on a coarser algebra it erases the inner condition on the finer algebra.